Small Mario, Big Wins
This is a pretty easy problem that's suitable for people new to puzzle solving:
There's a bootleg video game called Small Mario (original name is Xiao Ma Li), which is a gambling game with different kinds of fruit (and some other stuff).
Here's a gameplay video. It's played on a roulette-like board like this:    You can bet up to 9 credits for each item. The "REP." slots don't give any credits. The rest all give the amount of points right above their own icon in the betting section per bet:
Apple = 5  Watermelon = 20  Star = 30  7 = 40  Bar = 50  Bell = 20  Blue lemon (lol) = 15  Orange = 10  Grapes = 2
How do you maximize your wins?

But surely the game is rigged, right? :D

Nope. The devs just didn't care.

assuming the wheel isn't rigged, you should bet on the symbols that

 have positive expected value. these are the star (1.25), the 7 (1.66), the bar (2.08), the bell (1.66), and the blue lemon (1.25).

The more i think about it, the less this makes sense in my head and i'm also not certain that the game functions like i think it does, so i'll just hit post.

No, it's not. The game's just that simplistic.

@Nautilus: bootleg games have this air of complete lack of playtesting or thought put into them, I find them really endearing for these reasons

Yes, I agree. They have a raw, unpolished charm.
